# Lua - как получить переменную $status из Nginx

Tags: lua

Cобственно вопрос в заголовке. Необходимо получить переменную $status (current request status) из nginx в lua. Если например тело соообщения можно получить благодаря `ngx.req.read_body() ngx.req.get_body_data()` то каким образом можно получить $status. Большое спасибо за помощь.